# Calculator using delegates in C#.net .(arithmetic is unassigned)

Tags: c#, .net

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ArithmaticOperation
{
    class Program
    {
        delegate double ArithmaticDelegate(double x, double y);

        static void Menu()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Select an arithmatic operation");
            Console.WriteLine("1)Addition");
            Console.WriteLine("2)Subtraction");
            Console.WriteLine("3)Multiplication");
            Console.WriteLine("4)Division");
            Console.WriteLine("5)Remainder");
            Console.WriteLine("6)Quit");
        }

        static double Add(double a, double b)
        {   
            return a + b;
        }

        static double Subtract(double a, double b)
        {
            return a - b;
        }

        static double Multiply(double a, double b)
        {
            return a * b;
        }

        static double Divide(double a, double b)
        {
            return a / b;
        }

        static double Modulus(double a, double b)
        {
            return a % b;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int operation;
            ArithmaticDelegate arithmatic;
            double x, y;

            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter two numbers seperated by Enter");
                x = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                y = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Clear();

                Menu();
                operation = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                switch (operation)
                {
                    //Addition
                    case 1:
                        arithmatic = new ArithmaticDelegate(Add);
                        break;
                    //Subtraction
                    case 2:
                        arithmatic = new ArithmaticDelegate(Subtract);
                        break;
                    //Multiplication
                    case 3:
                        arithmatic = new ArithmaticDelegate(Multiply);
                        break;
                    //Division
                    case 4:
                        arithmatic = new ArithmaticDelegate(Divide);
                        break;
                    //Remainder
                    case 5:
                        arithmatic = new ArithmaticDelegate(Modulus);
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Exiting program");
                        break;
                }
                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine(arithmatic(x, y));
                        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue");
                        Console.ReadKey(true);
                        Console.Clear();

            } while (operation != 6);

        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to write a simple calculator using delegates. The code below would give an error at the line 81 "Console.WriteLine(arithmatic(x,y));" reporting that the variable arithmatic is unassigned local variable. I believe the cause has something to do with the variable scope in the do-while and the switch body, however the variable is declared outside the do-while so its scope should span the entire main method, and anything assigned to it from within the do-while and switch statement should remain in effect after its outside. Yet the compiler still report its uninitialized/unassigned

Comment: You don't have definite assignment of the variable if the default branch is taken. Instead of `break`, you could use `return`.

Comment: You `declare` the variable in line 51 all right, but you don't `assign` a value to it. As @JonathonChase points out, if the default branch is taken, the variable is left unassigned.That's what the compiler is complaining about.

Comment: Use `return` instead of `break` in your `default` block. Also you don't need to write `arithmatic = new ArithmaticDelegate(Add);` as `arithmatic = Add;` suffices - the same holds true for the other delegate assignments.

Comment: This also works and is a bit nicer to read and write: https://pastebin.com/iyreESNC

Comment: @JonathonChase thanks it works!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error message because arithmatic is not initialized in all the cases of switch statement (meaning not assigned in **all execution paths**).

To fix this issue: 
**either** have some dummy method and assign that dummy method in default

```
static double DummyMethod(double a, double b)
{
    return 6; // or any number other than 1 through 5
}
```

and in default case, `arithmatic = DummyMethod;`

**(or)** initialze as below:

So, to fix the error: please modify your programs to initialize arithematic as below:

```
ArithmaticDelegate arithmatic = null;
```

and then surround your arithematic call with if as below:

```
if (arithmatic != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(arithmatic(x, y));
}
```

**or** return in default case to skip the execution path when control enters into default case.